# Is it possible to set up preferrential IPs when in maintainance mode?

Tags: maintenance-mode

I've previously worked on Prestashop and there I had the choice to set my site in offline/maintance mode and then edit one ore more IP addresses in order other people to view the sites but not the commmon users and stills no login require and no additional host file settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible by default. The feature can be however extended via a module.

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to include the name of the module..

Answer (score 4):

Actually on Drupal you can create a new role and assign permission to this role to login in maintenance mode (Add permission "System > Use the site in maintenance mode").

If this is not what you want, then you can filter IP addresses on firewall /linux level. Please ask on https://serverfault.com/ if you need this kind of solution.

Comment: If I assign the permission to a custom role, how then I assign the custom role to my client?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, go to menu People > List > edit a selected User, then select, check the checkbox next to the newly created role and save the User. You need to have administrator role to do this and your administrator role needs following permissions: User:Administer permissions, User:Administer users

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Maybe there is a module for that. I would do it with an .htaccess host file.

Comment: It should be working with: allow from 000.000.000.000 to add my client's IP